# Que diferencia hay entre estos dos simbolos en php --> y =>

Tags: php

Quisiera saber la diferencia entre estos dos simbolos --> y => en php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nunca ví el operador --> en php. Si te refieres a "->" es el utilizado para referirse a un método u objeto dentro de un objeto. En otros lenguajes se utiliza el punto ".". Por ejemplo:

```
    Class MiClase{
       public $x = 0; //Variable pública de la clase "Miclase
       public miMetodo(){
           //... Contenido del método
       }
    }
    $objeto = new MiClase();
    $objeto->x = 5; //Se usa -> para "usar" la variable del objeto
    $objeto->miMetodo(); //Lo mismo para usar el método
```

El Operador => se utiliza como asignación de valores para un array. Por ejemplo:

```
   $miArray = array(
       'clave' => 'valor'
   );
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. soy nuevo en esto de la programación.

Comment: esta clase de respuestas son las que valen oro :)

Answer (score 3):

En php, los carácteres "->" hacen referencia a un objeto.

El típico ejemplo:

```
$coche->endender()
$coche->apagar()
```

Los carácteres "=>" son el operador igual o mayor que, (que también se utilizan en otras partes como en los vectores asociativos):

```
$coche = array(
    'marca' => 'SEAT',
    'color' => 'blanco',
    'modelo' => 'Ibiza'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

El operador `=>`, se utiliza como un mecanismo de acceso para *matrices*. Esto significa que lo que está en el lado izquierdo de él tendrá un valor correspondiente de lo que está en el lado derecho de él en el contexto de la *matriz*. Esto puede usarse para establecer valores de cualquier tipo aceptable en un índice correspondiente de una *matriz*. El índice puede ser asociativo (basado en cadena) o numérico.

```
<?php
   $miArray = array(
      0 => 'Grande',
      1 => 'Mediano',
      2 => 'Pequeño'
    );
 ?>
```

El operador `->`, se utiliza en el ámbito del objeto para acceder a métodos y propiedades de un objeto. Su significado es decir que lo que está a la derecha del operador es un miembro del objeto instanciado en la variable del lado izquierdo del operador. Instanciado es el término clave aquí.

```
<?php
    $obj = new MiObjeto(); // Crear una nueva instancia de MiObjeto en $obj
    $obj->thisProperty = 'Fred'; // Establezca una propiedad en el objeto $obj denominado thisProperty
    $obj->getProperty(); // Llame a un método del objeto $obj denominado getProperty
?>
```

Fuente: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037290/what-does-this-mean-in-php-or)

Answer (score 0):

**(A) `->` o `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`**

En PHP, el símbolo `->` es un operador de objeto.

Se usa para acceder a un miembro de un objeto. Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
//Una clase (Objeto)
class A
{
    function foo()
    {
            echo 'función foo';
    }

}

$a = new A();
$a->foo();

?>
```

Como dato curioso `->` **no es mencionado** entre [los operadores de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.php).

En algunos casos, para acceder a los miembros de un objeto se usa `::` en vez de `->`, en otros, se puede usar cualquiera de los indistintamente. Para más detalles sobre esto [puedes ver esta pregunta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173501/whats-the-difference-between-double-colon-and-arrow-in-php).

Cuando PHP encuentra errores relativos a `->` le llama de la siguiente manera: `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`.

Por ejemplo, en un código como éste:

```
<?php 

    $sTexto="-> se llama T_OBJECT_OPERATOR";
    ->; //error
    echo $Texto;

?>
```

Tendremos derecho al error siguiente:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (**T_OBJECT_OPERATOR**),
>   expecting end of file in ...

---

**(B) `=>` o `T_DOUBLE_ARROW`**

El símbolo `=>` se usa en la sintaxis de las matrices (arrays) para separar las claves (a la izquierda de `=>` de los valores, que se encuentran a la derecha.

El [manual de PHP indica su uso en la sintaxis de los arrays](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array.php) (matrices):

> ... Sintaxis "índice => valores", separados por comas, define índice y
>   valores.

Cuando muestra errores relativos a él, PHP le llama `T_DOUBLE_ARROW`.

De hecho, el siguiente código:

```
<?php 

    $sTexto="=> se llama T_DOUBLE_ARROW";
    =>; //error
    echo $Texto;
 ?>
```

Arrojaría un mensaje de error como éste:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=>' (**T_DOUBLE_ARROW**),
>   expecting end of file in ...

---

**(C) ¿Dónde aparecen en la Documentación de PHP?**

En el apartado llamado [Lista de componentes léxicos del analizador](http://php.net/manual/es/tokens.php) del Manual de PHP encontraremos una lista de los componentes léxicos del lenguaje, entre los cuales están por supuesto `->`y `=>`. El símbolo `-->` por su parte no existe en PHP.